# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.ProxySelector

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror

I'm running into a problem with a java app constantly throwing:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.ProxySelector.

I am running Suse Linux 10.3 and running java 1.6.0. My CLASSPATH is set to

> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/lib.

No other users seem to be having this error so I'm assuming its my setup. For those wondering the app is yamj (http://code.google.com/p/moviejukebox/)

Any ideas as to what maybe missing or what I maybe doing wrong?

Edit the full trace of the error is as follows:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.ProxySelector
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$5.run(HttpURLConnection.java:736)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:732)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:672)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
>       at com.moviejukebox.thetvdb.tools.XMLHelper.getEventReader(XMLHelper.java:19)
>       at com.moviejukebox.thetvdb.model.Mirrors.(Mirrors.java:30)
>       at com.moviejukebox.thetvdb.TheTVDB.(TheTVDB.java:37)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.TheTvDBPlugin.(TheTvDBPlugin.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.DatabasePluginController.getMovieDatabasePlugin(DatabasePluginController.java:96)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.DatabasePluginController.access$000(DatabasePluginController.java:30)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.DatabasePluginController$1.initialValue(DatabasePluginController.java:44)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.DatabasePluginController$1.initialValue(DatabasePluginController.java:39)
>       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
>       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
>       at com.moviejukebox.plugin.DatabasePluginController.scan(DatabasePluginController.java:70)
>       at com.moviejukebox.MovieJukebox.updateMovieData(MovieJukebox.java:1051)
>       at com.moviejukebox.MovieJukebox.access$100(MovieJukebox.java:80)
>       at com.moviejukebox.MovieJukebox$4.call(MovieJukebox.java:613)
>       at com.moviejukebox.MovieJukebox$4.call(MovieJukebox.java:600)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java

Comment: Please post some code showing what you're doing and explaining how this is related to your code.  Othewise you question is likely to get closed as "not programming related".

Comment: Sounds more like this is a plea for tech support rather than programming support

Comment: I guess it is kind of tech support-ish more then programming but it looked like a library issue so I figured it would be something simple that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

ProxySelector is an abstract class.  Are you trying to instantiate it directly?

Comment: @Jim: Lets say Shinda is instantiating it directly, will it result in a NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: Only in strange situations where the compiler can't detect that at runtime due to the compile-time class definition not being the same one used at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> My CLASSPATH is set to
>   /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/lib.

don't think that should be in your CLASSPATH

try clearing the CLASSPATH and running it

Comment: Not having the class path didn't make a difference with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't have to put "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk/lib" on your classpath.  The "java" command should put all of the standard J2SE libraries on the bootclasspath without you doing anything.

Second, it would help if you gave us the full stacktrace, not just the exception message.  I suspect that the real problem is that java.net.ProxySelector (or something it depends on) is failing during static initialization.  But only a stacktrace would confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's second result in google search on this error, I want to post this piece of code I found [at some forum](http://www.tutorials.de/java/271758-exception-thread-timeout-guard-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror.html) that helped me with the same exception. Cannot explain in details - it was just a quick test project for me, so I didn't have time for deeper investigation.

```
static { 
  try {
    Class c = Class.forName("sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector");
    if (c != null && ProxySelector.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
       theProxySelector = (ProxySelector) c.newInstance();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    theProxySelector = null;
  }
}
```