# Java: Program randomly stopped working because of "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class me.ryan.Resources"

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I've been programming a game, and I've had a class called Resources for a while. For some reason, when I make almost no edits to the class, it stops working. This is my Resources class:

```
public class Resources {

public static final BufferedImage background = load("/background.png");
public static final BufferedImage introBackground = load("/introBackground.png");
public static final BufferedImage sneem = load("/sneem.png");
public static final BufferedImage grass = load("/grass.png");
public static final BufferedImage wall = load("/wall.png");

public static BufferedImage load(String path){
    URL url = Resources.class.getResource(path);
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

ALSO: I made this class from scratch, I'm not using any libraries or that kind of thing.

Comment: relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956789/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-java-net-proxyselecto?rq=1

Comment: None of these solutions helped me. Also, I didn't change the classpath at all from when it worked and when it didn't - it stayed the same.

Comment: What did you change between working and non-working versions?

Comment: There is no package "me.ryan" in the class.

Comment: @tak3shi I just left it out it's actually in there in my actual code

Comment: @Dave I changed nothing in the Resources class, which is odd; I created a class called Map which loads and parses an image loaded with Resource.load

Comment: @RyanMickey Stephen's answer below is very likely to be correct. I only wanted to rule out other possibilities before providing a similar answer (because of the "almost no edits" bit). Move the `getResource` call inside the `try` and change it to catch all `Exception`s.

Comment: @Dave thanks. This worked

Answer (score 2):

This message ....

> “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class me.ryan.Resources”

means that the initialization of the statics for your `Resources` class has failed.  The exception message does not say why, but the stacktrace will probably say that ... in the nested exception chain.

The failure will have happened because one of your `load` calls has failed due to an *unchecked* exception that was not caught.

---

Looking at the code for `load` **I am guessing** that the exception was a `NullPointerException`, and that it happened because the

```
Resources.class.getResource(path)
```

call has returned `null` instead of a `URL` object.  It will do that if the classloader cannot find a resource whose pathname corresponds to what you asked for.

If this is what is going on then the root cause is that you have used the wrong paths. or your build / deploy procedure has not placed the required image files where the classloader expects th find them; e.g. in the JAR file, if you are running from an executable JAR.